# Foreach function in an efficient way

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

```
$name = array(
    'maxgebruikers' => $_POST['maxgebruikers'], 
    'maxplaylist'   => $_POST['maxplaylist']
);

//foreach()
```

I want a `foreach()` function that will insert into my database, how can I do this in an efficient way. It need to have only `INSERT INTO` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you mean(untested):

```
foreach($name as $key=>$value) {
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO $database_name, table_name (tablerow_name, tablerow_name)
VALUES('{$key}', '{$value}')");
}
```

Let me know if it worked!

Comment: You're providing a MySQLi example, why couldn't you have used a prepared statement and bind variables to go with that?

Comment: That one is not secure. I agree with @MarkBaker. Don't use that code in a public project.